# How to integrate path patterns with cypher morpheus?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying use Cypher query with Spark. I'm following this guide: https://github.com/opencypher/morpheus
but I'm not able to use path patterns `p=()-[]->()`.
My main problem is that I want to calculate the level of relationship.
For example:
`p=(u)-[:rel]-(f)  return length(p)`
Thank's for answer.